# Why do statements get executed more than once in paint or paintComponent methods?

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint, paintcomponent

I am trying to draw and paint some geometric shapes based on some calculations inside the `paint()` or `paintComponent()` methods. However, I realized that the printing and other calculation statements inside `paint()` or `paintComponent()` are executed 2 or sometimes 3 times. For example the print statement in the following code is executed twice and the word "help" is printed twice in the console:

```
public class Skeleton extends JPanel {
public void paint(Graphics g){
     Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
     g2d.drawOval(50, 50, 100, 100);
     System.out.println("help");
}
```

and then in the console the printed part is like this:

```
help
help
```

and here is my `main()` method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java 2D Skeleton");
    frame.add(new Skeleton());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(870, 890);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

What is worse is that, if I have a class public variable and I am increasing its value by 1 within the `paint()` method. This results in having the value increased by 2. 
I have read somewhere in this website such that the method `paint()` automatically invokes three other methods, which I thing they are causing this problem.
Also I have tried some suggested solution on another website to override the method `paintComponent()` instead of the method `paint()`. However I still have the same problem.
Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You are right to override paintComponent instead of paint.  I think the issue here is that paintComponent should do one thing, paint your component.  Any number of things can cause a call to repaint() which will call your paintComponent, so it's not really guaranteed when and how often this method will execute.  Doing calculations and keeping track of variables should probably be a part of a separate model class that your component can look at to know what to draw.

Comment: Thanks for responding but I need it to draw shapes based on the values and calculations of some variables. Besides, I need to call other method to do other staff based on the shapes positions. Maybe a possible solution if applicable is to do the calculations in a different method but within this new method I make calls to the paintComponent method to do the painting. Is this possible?

Comment: You should never call paintComponent() directly. If you change a property of your class that causes the painting to change you invoke repaint() and then Swing will determine when to repaint the component.

Answer (score 1):

This question has probably been forgotten but I stumbled upon it and would like to help out anyone else who does too. The solution I found was to use JApplet's init() method. There you can do all the calculations you need. Then, if you want, you can also create a timer that responds at a specified interval to call repaint() and do iteration-ish work. That way, you can leave everything except the actual drawing code out of paint. It would look something like this:

```
public void init()
    {
      //do calculations here

    javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000 / frameRate, new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
        {
           //this is called every so often. Can link to update loops or be an 
           //update loop itself.
            repaint();
        }
    } );
    timer.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{       
    //All the actual drawing code for the shapes goes here.
}
```